# the asset cannot be uploaded Error in QTP

Tags: qtp

I am super new to HP Qc and HP QTP. 
I have setup the HP-QC server and trying to connect from QTP.
but when I am saving the test, error pops up which says "The asset cannot be uploaded"
I didnt find anything on internet related to this, HP support sucks. 
They reply an email after two weeks.
Is there anyone over here who can help me to understand this error. 
please feel free to reformat if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be conflict between QTP script in server and your local machine. Best way is try doing save AS into different test.

[Blog - Sham332](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/QTP)

Comment: Actually this is new script at new location.